# Leer matriz desde archivo dónde cada carácter indica un color y representarla como rectángulos en un Canvas

Tags: python, string, tkinter, diccionarios, bucle-for

Verán, soy un principiante en Python y en esto de programar y tengo muchas dudas sobre qué hacer. Tengo un archivo .txt con una matriz 14x14 compuesta de Strings. La matriz es la siguiente:

```
caccrrrvmdracm
vcrracaaamdarm
vmvmdaccdddaar
cmddvvdmcrrvva
acamcvammavvac
dvdadvdrdmvvvm
cmdrcavrvrmccm
ccrmdvrccrrvcd
vvdacvadvvdmac
mardvcccdvcddc
dmmmvcddarccmv
dcmvmrrravvaca
vadadarraraaac
amdadmmacvcvac
```

Cada letra significa un color, y a cada letra le he asignado su "definición"  utilizando un diccionario.

```
    #Diccionario
colores={
'a' : '#ffff00', #Amarillo
'c' : '#00ffff', #Cyan
'd' : '#ffc90e', #Dorado
'm' : '#800080', #Morado
'r' : '#ff0000', #Rojo
'v' : '#00bb00'  #Verde
}
```

Ahora debo hacer que mi archivo Python lea la matriz y la imprima en un tkinter (280, 280). Hasta ahora solo he logrado que me imprima 1 solo cuadro en pantalla:

```
c.create_rectangle(20,20,40,40,fill="#800080",outline="")
```

Me imagino que puedo hacer que imprima la matriz con `for` como se estila, sin embargo, no puedo lograr leer el archivo correctamente ni hacer llamar correctamente los elementos en el diccionario de datos.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con el diccionario y el `Canvas` tienes ya la idea bastante perfilada. Leer el archivo no requiere nada en especial:

1. Un `for in` que itere sobre el archivo retornando cada fila.
2. Eliminamos el salto de línea final de cada fila.
3. Un segundo `for in` anidado en el anterior que itera sobre cada carácter de la fila.

Es decir, algo así:

```
with open("datos.txt") as f:
    for linea in f:
        for c in linea.rstrip():
            print(c)
```

La segunda clave es que para cada rectángulo debes proporcionar las coordenadas adecuadas para el vértice superior izquierdo y el vértice inferior derecho de cada rectángulo. Básicamente la idea es:

1. Inicializamos los valores `x` e `y` del vértice superior a 0 y los del vértice inferior a la anchura/altura de cada rectángulo.
2. Para cada fila dibujada incrementamos los valores de `y` de ambos vértices en la altura del rectángulo. Los valores de `x` son reseteados a los valores iniciales.
3. Por cada cuadrado dibujado en una fila incrementamos el valor de `x` de ambos vértices en la anchura del rectángulo.

Todo junto sería algo así:

```
x0, y0 = 0, 0
x1, y1 = 20, 20
with open("datos.txt") as f:    
    for row in f:
        for c in row.rstrip():
            canvas.create_rectangle(x0, y0, x1, y1,
                                    fill=colores[c],
                                    outline=""
                                   )
            x0, x1 = x1, x1 + 20
        y0, y1 = y1, y1 + 20
        x0, x1 = 0, 20
```

Donde `canvas` es la instancia de `tkinter.Canvas`, `"datos.txt"` la ruta al archivo y `colores` tu diccionario. Obtener el valor de un diccionarios mediante su clave es tan simple como `diccionario[clave]`, aunque esto llevará a un `KeyError` si la clave no existe, si esto puede ocurrir podemos recurrir a [`dict.get()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get)

Un ejemplo completo de código sería:

```
import tkinter as tk


class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent

        self.canvas_height = 280
        self.canvas_width = 280
        self.file_path = "datos.txt"

        self.colors = {'a' : '#ffff00', #Amarillo
                       'c' : '#00ffff', #Cyan
                       'd' : '#ffc90e', #Dorado
                       'm' : '#800080', #Morado
                       'r' : '#ff0000', #Rojo
                       'v' : '#00bb00'  #Verde
                      }

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self,
                                height=self.canvas_height,
                                width=self.canvas_width
                                )
        self.canvas.pack()
        self.matriz = self.load_matriz(self.file_path)
        self._draw_matriz()

    @staticmethod
    def load_matriz(path):
        with open(path) as f:
            return [[c for c in line.rstrip()] for line in f]

    def _draw_matriz(self):
        rect_h = self.canvas_height / len(self.matriz)
        rect_w = self.canvas_width / len(self.matriz[0])

        x0, y0 = 0, 0
        x1, y1 = rect_w, rect_h

        for row in self.matriz:
            for c in row:
                self.canvas.create_rectangle(x0, y0, x1, y1,
                                             fill=self.colors.get(c, "#000000"),
                                             outline="")
                x0, x1 = x1, x1 + rect_w
            y0, y1 = y1, y1 + rect_h
            x0, x1 = 0, rect_w


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = App(root)
    app.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
    app.mainloop()
```

> El código es para Python 3, pero es compatible con Python 2 con solo cambiar el import por `import Tkinter as tk`.

En este caso el contenido del fichero es cargado en una matriz (lista anidada) y se calcula automáticamente la altura de cada rectángulo en función de los datos del archivo y el tamaño del `Canvas`. Cualquier carácter que no sea un color definido en el diccionario será representado como un cuadrado negro (para lo que se usa el método `dict.get()`). Esto permite que el código sea más flexible pudiendo, por ejemplo, con solo algunos cambios conseguir que se redibuje el canvas si redimensionamos la ventana, cargar matrices con distinto tamaño o no cuadradas, etc.

Con todo obtenemos un colorido resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]